# Requesting Array of objects using axios in Reactjs but getting error: this.state.employees.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

Code:

```
  import React from 'react';
        import axios from 'axios';
        import { Component } from 'react';
        
        class DataRetrieve extends Component{
            constructor(){
                super();
                this.state= {
                    employees: []
                }
            }
               componentDidMount(){
                  axios.get('https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees').then((resp)=> {
                    this.setState({
                        employees: resp.data
                    })
                    console.log(resp.data);
                })
            }
            render(){
                return(
                    <div>
        
                        <h3>API CALL</h3>
              {this.state.employees.map(employee =><li key={employee.id}>{employee.employee_name}</li>)}
                    </div>
                )
            }
        }
        
        export default DataRetrieve;
```

Here I make an API request using Axios but it shows nothing except h3. only prints data on console not on screen. Have I made any mistake in my code?

Answer (score 1):

`resp.data` is an array of objects so `resp.data.employee_name` is undefined. Either use first element (`resp.data[0]?.employee_name`) or iterate to get each object.

either way I would change the state name from "name" to "employees" and the init value to an empty array instead of an empty string cause thats what the data is:

```
this.setState({ employees: resp.data })
```

to display the data using map:

```
{
  this.state.employees.map(employee => <li key={employee.id}>{employee.employee_name}</li>)
}
```

the full code should be:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Component } from "react";

class DataRetrieve extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      employees: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees")
      .then((resp) => {
        console.log(resp.data.data);
        this.setState({
          employees: resp.data.data
        });
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>API CALL</h3>
        {this.state.employees.map((employee) => (
          <li key={employee.id}>{employee.employee_name}</li>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DataRetrieve;
```

Comment: I have iterate it using map method inside render like this {this.state.name.map(names =><li key={names.id}>{names.employee_name}</li>)} but it still gives error

Comment: I added the code to my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: it is not working gives an error like this.state.employees.map is not a function.